# combining insert sql statment with select statement for more than 1 value

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to combine an insert sql statement with a select statement, I successfully combined this statement:

```
insert into dbo.sessions (se_user) select user_id from dbo.users where username = 'bader'", badersql);
```

What I need now is to insert another value in the same sql statement, like this:

```
insert into dbo.sessions (se_user,*se_ip*) select user_id from dbo.users...
```

As you notice there is `se_ip` here in the second statement, the value will be from a text box, how can I combine it with my sql statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.sessions (se_user, se_ip)
SELECT user_id, @ipAddress FROM dbo.users WHERE username = @username
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select constant from a parameter:

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"insert into dbo.sessions (se_user, se_ip) 
        select user_id, @text from dbo.users...", connection) {
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("text", myTextBox.Text);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: could you please provide your answer with an example ? , thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into dbo.sessions 
    (se_user,se_ip) 
    select user_id, @TextBoxValue
        from dbo.users...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first insert statement that you have mentioned in your question and then add an update statement to modify the data as you need to

OR

I am assuming you have the value of the textbox in a variable and so you can use something like `SELECT user_id,@yourtextboxvalue from userstable...`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add another field to the `select` portion of your insert statement

```
insert into dbo.sessions (se_user,*se_ip*) select user_id, other_value from dbo.users ...
```

If the value comes from a text box,, it depends on how you're running the insert statement.  You'll probably have to set a parameter to your command object.  see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675101%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more details.